# Sql Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 [ODBC_Driver_Manager]_Data_source_name_not_found_and_no_default_driver_specified

Tags: vbscript, sql-server-2012, asp-classic, ado, windows-server-2012-r2

Just moved Web App from windows server 2003 to 2012 R2 x64 and upgraded 
`MS SQL Server from 2000` to `2012`. Web App is in `Classic ASP (VB Script)`. It was working fine on the old server and some part of the application works fine here too. But for some part of the application it's getting error. The error happens when executing `ADO.Command` and `ADODB.recordset` with stored procedure and parameters.

> 80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC_Driver_Manager]_Data_source_name_not_found_and_no_default_driver_specified

This is the function which is blowing up;

```
Function GetOrders(pDate)
    dim storedProcedure, adoCommandObject,parameterObject,resultTable
    storedProcedure = 4
    set adoCommandObject = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")     
    adoCommandObject.ActiveConnection = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSRVR2012;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=readonlyUser;Password=readonlyUserPassword;" 
    adoCommandObject.CommandText = "[dbo].[usp_Order_Get]"
    adoCommandObject.CommandType = storedProcedure
    set parameterObject = adoCommandObject.Parameters
    parameterObject.Append = adoCommandObject.CreateParameter("from", adVarchar,adParamInput,255,pDate)
    set resultTable =Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

    html = "No record found"
    Err.Clear
    on error resume next
        set resultTable = adoCommandObject.Execute        
    if err.Number = 0 then
        if not resultTable.EOF then
            html="Html header..."
            while not resultTable.EOF
                html = html & "Html..."
            resultTable.MoveNext            
            wend
            html = html
        end if
    Else
        set resultTable = nothing
        set adoCommandObject = nothing
        Response.Write "Error:"& Err.Description
        Response.End
    end if
    GetOrders=html
    set resultTable = nothing
    set adoCommandObject = nothing
End Function
```

This is the function which works with the same connection string;

```
Function GetOrders
Dim rs
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select top * 1 from [dbo].[orders];", "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSRVR2012;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=readonlyUser;Password=readonlyUserPassword;"
Dim html: html="No record found"
if not rs.eof then
    html = html & "Generate html...."
end if
rs.close
GetOrders=html
End Function
```

**Note:** On the old server it was using `DSN` in the connection string but on this new server I changed the connection string like above just to avoid DSN. Database mydb on SQL Server 2012 is running on 2005 compatibility mode.

IIS is 8.5.9600.16384. Enable 32 Bit Application is `False` for Application Pool and running as Integrated Mode.

Comment: Get rid of `Data Source=`  I am surprised `Data Source=DRIVER={SQL Server}` works at all as its ambiguous.  It would be `Data Source=;` for an empty parameter.

Comment: I updated the OP.

Comment: You could try switching to the more modern [Native Client](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/)

Comment: Used the first CS from the link for native though error is changed and some weird error in the IIS logs as Expected_identifier.